# Rails / Devise - Passing Username into Profile Build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, friendly-id

I am currently working on a rails project using devise, and I have ran into a bit of an issue.

I have the default devise:install running with my User model, and I have a another model called Profile. It `belongs_to :user`, and the user `has_one :profile`.

The issue I have, is that I require the user to have a username, so it must be done on sign up; so this is passed into the users table through devise. But I need to use the username for the users profile url, and this means crossing an attribute from the Users table, with the Profiles view.

In the user model I am using: `after_create :build_profile` to build a profile for that user. This creates a profile with `first_name` and `last_name` etc into the profiles table.

So, using the 'friendly_id' gem I can link to attributes from the 'profiles/index'page to the users profile. The problem is I can only use things that have been passed into the profiles table, such as `first_name` or `last_name` I can't link to `:username` as that is in the Users table, not the Profiles table.

In the profile_model.rb file, at the moment I am using:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :first_name
```

and in the profiles/index.html.erb file I am using:

```
<% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
<p><%= link_to profile.user.username, profile %></p>
<% end %>
```

This works for making URLs such as /profiles/John but John is no good as it is not unique.

Comment: Have you considered just using users#show as the profile page?

Comment: Such a simple solution! I hadn't realised that you could have a standard users controller, I thought it was locked down to devise. Made a users controller and passed in the profiles info and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using nested routes?  In your routes.rb file you can have:

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
```

That way, you then use something like `<%= link_to user_profile_path(@profile.user, @profile), @profile %>`